# Alternate way to program a range slider with distinct options

Tags: javascript, input, range, datalist, rangeslider

I am trying to program, in Javascript, a custom range slider with styled datalist options. If you slide a selector over the different values (ex: 780mn, 785nm, 808nm ect) on the bar, then different information would appear below specific to those values and the value you are currently on becomes highlighted. Here's an example image of what the slider would look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LH2X.png.

I've currently set this up as an input with type=range and the different points are datalist options. However based on what I've researched, editing the CSS for datalists is very browser specific. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can program this functionality because I'm stomped? Thanks in advance!!

My current code is the following:

```
    <div>
      <input type="range" min="780" max="1070" value="780" list="wavelenghtOptions" class="slider" id="sliderRange" />
      <datalist id="wavelenghtOptions">
        <option value="780" label="780">
        <option value="785" label="785">
        <option value="808" label="808">
        <option value="830" label="830">
        <option value="852" label="852">
        <option value="905" label="905">
        <option value="915" label="915">
        <option value="940" label="940">
        <option value="945" label="945">
        <option value="957" label="957">
        <option value="1064" label="1064">
        <option value="1070" label="1070">
      </datalist>
      <div>
        <div>
          <h3><span id="waveTitle"></span> nm</h3>
          <p id="waveDescription"></p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>Legend</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>Single-mode</li>
            <li>Multimode</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <script>
        var slider = document.getElementById("sliderRange");
        var titleOutput = document.getElementById("waveTitle");
        var descriptionOutput = document.getElementById("waveDescription");
        var wavelengths = [
          {
            range:780,
            description:"This is a description for the 780 nm range.",
          },
          {
            range:785,
            description:"This is a description for the 785 nm range.",
          },
          {
            range:808,
            description:"This is a description for the 808 nm range.",
          },
          {
            range:830,
            description:"This is a description for the 830 nm range.",
          },
          {
            range:852,
            description:"This is a description for the 852 nm range.",
          },
          {
            range:905,
            description:"This is a description for the 905 nm range.",
          },
          {
            range:915,
            description:"This is a description for the 915 nm range.",
          },
          {
            range:940,
            description:"This is a description for the 940 nm range.",
          },
          {
            range:945,
            description:"This is a description for the 945 nm range.",
          },
          {
            range:975,
            description:"This is a description for the 975 nm range.",
          },
          {
            range:1064,
            description:"This is a description for the 1064 nm range.",
          },
          {
            range:1070,
            description:"This is a description for the 1070 nm range.",
          }
        ]

        titleOutput.innerHTML = slider.value;

        slider.oninput = function(){
          for(let i=0; i<wavelengths.length; i++){
            if(this.value === wavelengths[i]['range'].toString()){
              titleOutput.innerHTML = this.value;
              descriptionOutput.innerHTML = wavelengths[i]['description'];
            }
          }

        }
      </script>
```